# WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers) spawning

Tags: nginx, php

i have a problem with nginx and php-fpm, i searched already in this form but i found no solution for it.

Server:
32 cores
64gb memory

Settings:

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  32;


events {
    worker_connections 2048;
}
```

in the php-fpm config

```
pm.max_children = 1500
pm.start_servers = 500
pm.min_spare_servers = 500
pm.max_spare_servers = 500
```

it work for few minutes, but if we have more users on the server, i got follow errror message:

[06-Oct-2014 15:23:20] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 483 idle, and 1068 total children

and the page is very slow and a lot of users have the 502 bad gateway message

The load average is about 20 20 20

i tried a lot of differnt settings, but i don't know what is the reason, i hope sombody can help.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

What is your "net.core.somaxconn" value?
It can be found by doing  "cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn". It should be big enough to handle large number of requests in your case. The default is 128 which is very less in your case. Make it 2048 if its less.

Also the "listen.backlog" directive in php-fpm should be big enough to queue requests. The somaxconn value should be greater than backlog value.

Answer (score 0):

You have 32 worker processes which accept up to 2048 connections *each* [(yes, each)](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections).

This means that your nginx accepts up to 65536 simultaneous connections.

But your PHP-FPM will have at most 1500 instances ready to handle PHP requests.

Now, depending on your ratio of PHP to static file requests, you are short of available PHP-FPM processes.

Assuming that the average PHP/static ratio on a typical webpage of yours is 1:5, you could (in theory) serve up to 7,500 parallel requests. All others will get a bad gateway error.

This is just a theoretical figure, there are many factors to take into account (keep-alive, caching, kernel TCP settings, etc.) to determine the actual maximums, but this should give you an idea where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, i use at moment the unix socket not the TCP/IP

i changed it now to:
somaxconn: 2048
and listen.backlog: 1024

both was on 128.

here again an example of the error logs (this was before i changed it)

```
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:32] NOTICE: [pool www] child 23114 exited with code 0 after 234.275112 seconds from start
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:32] NOTICE: [pool www] child 25056 started
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:45] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 108 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:46] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 116 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:47] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 132 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:48] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 164 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:49] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 196 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:50] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 228 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:51] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 0 idle, and 260 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:52] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 11 idle, and 292 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:53] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 5 idle, and 324 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:54:54] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 36 idle, and 356 total children
    [07-Oct-2014 11:55:02] WARNING: [pool www] child 25306, script '/srv/www/examplepage.com/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing too slow (13.037138 sec), logging
    [07-Oct-2014 11:55:02] WARNING: [pool www] child 24865, script '/srv/www/examplepage.com/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php") executing too slow (12.989517 sec), logging
```

this happen in 10 secounds, from 10 activ fpm processes to more than 400.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sadly not fixed, i installed now new relic, and here an example what happen when the php-fpm processes increase suddenly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIXRp.jpg

the server is not fully occupied at this time.

It looks like a problem with redis (i doesn't install memcached).